# Using mock-maker-inline Mockito plugin on IBM JVM 1.8

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I'm trying to mock a static method of a final class : Files.exist by example.

I read that I have to user a mock-maker-inline mockito plugin so I set it up :

I put this :

```
mock-maker-inline
```

in : src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker

and then I mocked my class and try to verify that my mock is called :

```java
@PrepareForTest(Files.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class StaticFinalMethodTests
{

  @InjectMocks
  private FileManipulationClass fileManipulationClass;

  @Before
  public void setUp()
  {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void fileManipulationTest() throws IOException
  {
    Mockito.when(Files.exists(Mockito.nullable(Path.class))).thenReturn(false);

    Files.exists(getDummyPath());

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Files.class);
    Files.exists(getDummyPath());
  }

  private Path getDummyPath()
  {
    return Paths.get("/dummy/path");
  }

}
```

And I have this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:226)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:64)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1855)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:62)
    at com.example.unitTest.GenericTestWithStatic.lambda$0(GenericTestWithStatic.java:17)
    at com.example.unitTest.GenericTestWithStatic$$Lambda$1.00000000104C10B0.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:959)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:591)
    at com.example.unitTest.GenericTestWithStatic.initStaticMocks(GenericTestWithStatic.java:17)
    at com.example.unitTest.ko.StaticFinalMethodTests.setUp(StaticFinalMethodTests.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:133)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.ClassLoader$CompoundEnumeration@9e7fde3c
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:94)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:48)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:18)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.preLoadPluginLoader(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:49)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.configuration.PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.process(PowerMockitoInjectingAnnotationEngine.java:37)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.injectSpiesAndInjectToSetters(AnnotationEnabler.java:61)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:56)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker. (This mock maker is not supported on Android.)

Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : IBM Corporation
JVM vendor version : 2.8
JVM name           : IBM J9 VM
JVM version        : pwa6480sr3fp10-20160720_02 (SR3 FP10)
JVM info           : JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64 Compressed References 20160719_312156 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20160719_1144_B312156
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20160629_120284.01
GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20160719_1144_B312156_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160719_312156
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0

    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:171)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadImpl(PluginLoader.java:89)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy requires retransformation for creating inline mocks. This feature is unavailable on the current VM.

You cannot use this mock maker on this VM
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:103)
    ... 35 more
```

i used power-mockito 2.0.0 with mockito 2.7.22

is there something I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Never too late to answer an open question...

I had the same issue using an IBM JDK 8.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invoking the beforeTestMethod method on PowerMock test listener org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler@c6c71aa4 failed.
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:84)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:250)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:61)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1951)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:108)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.doCreateMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:61)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:53)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:40)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:181)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:98)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:55)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.ClassLoader$1@af2e2d5
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:65)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:50)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:19)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:16)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.<clinit>(MockUtil.java:28)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:436)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:52)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

It appears as if you are running an incomplete JVM installation that might not support all tooling APIs
Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : IBM Corporation
JVM vendor version : 2.8
JVM name           : IBM J9 VM
JVM version        : pwa6480sr1fp10-20150711_01 (SR1 FP10)
JVM info           : JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 Pro amd64-64 Compressed References 20150630_255633 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20150625_95081.01
GC   - R28_jvm.28_20150630_1742_B255633_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20150630_255633
OS name            : Windows 10 Pro
OS version         : 10.0

    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:234)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Byte Buddy requires retransformation for creating inline mocks. This feature is unavailable on the current VM.

You cannot use this mock maker on this VM
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:120)
    ... 47 more
```

So, I can't explain the reason nor origin, but I decided to not use anymore IBM JDK and instead of it, I downloaded and configured a JDK Oracle version 1.8.0_291.

[image]

After that, the exception and bug were removed.